# What are the allowed characters for Android logcat?

Tags: logcat, android-logcat

I looked at [the document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html), but could not find the information about the legitimate character set.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

The following code:

```
Log.d("debug", "123456-Test1Line1-123456\r\n123456-Test1Line2-123456");
```

generates the the following **occasionally**:

```
123456-Test1Line2-123456
```

The following code:

```
Log.d("debug", "123456-Test2Line1-123456\n123456-Test2Line2-123456");
```

generates the following **consistently**:

```
06-28 01:33:21.839 11497-15151/net.mydomain.myapp D/debug: 123456-Test2Line1-123456
                                                          123456-Test2Line2-123456
```

The following code:

```
Log.d("debug", "123456-Test3Line1-123456\r123456-Test3Line2-123456");
```

outputs nothing.
It looks like that "\r" should be avoided.
I am fairly sure that "\r" used to be OK. I have been using it extensively (outputting contents written to a files to logcat for debugging).

Comment: I'd think it highly unlikely that Logcat supports Windows line endings (\r\n) rather than *nix (\n only).